# Trying to convert my sudo command into a bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, sudo

I am currently working a creating a script to run a file located on my drive. I have it correct if I wanted to run it in terminal.

```
sudo /Applications/Banks\ Ultra\ Client/rcuninstall
```

I would like to create a bash script that can do the exact same thing. I need it to be bash to push out to other machines using Jamf. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

If that command works on terminal, it should work in bash, sans maybe the sudo.  The main thing you'll have to worry about is the script's format, which depends on which bash shell your OS uses.  Check out some bash scripts I've created in the past as examples:  https://github.com/OpenDataAlex/kettle-helper-scripts

While they don't do exactly what you're wanting to do, I think they'll help you get where you want to go.  Also be mindful of escaping characters that can bork the command up.